# Apply a function if id equals X

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame like this

```
   id        subid        a
1  1         1            2 
2  1         1            10 
3  1         1            20
4  1         2            30
5  1         2            35 
6  1         2            36 
7  1         2            40
8  2         2            20
9  2         2            29
10 2         2            30
```

And I want to calculate and save the value of the mean of variable "a" for each id. For example I want the mean of the variable "a" if id=2. And then save that result on a list

This is what I have so far:

```
for i in range(2):

results=[]

if df.iloc[:,3]==i:
     value=np.mean(df)

results.append(value)
```

Comment: That's a pandas DataFrame? If not please correct the tag with the appropriate library. Also will you fix the indentation on your program?

Comment: `df.groupby('id')['a'].mean()` ?

Comment: Yes is a pandas df. Im sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is:

```py
df.groupby('id')['a'].mean()
```

It will return mean of both `1` and `2` but if you want to take only mean of `2` then you can do this:

```py
df.groupby('id')['a'].mean()[2]
```

By doing this you're only taking mean of a column whose id is `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Problems here,

1. results=[] should be out of loops, otherwise for each time the loop runs, result resets to [].
2. I'm aware that iloc[:,2] is a column you're looking for.
3. value = df['a'].mean()